# Alternative to Qgrid for displaying "pretty" dataframes in notebooks

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, qgrid

I wanted to use some library to have better display of pandas dataframe in notebooks (ie allow sorting of columns, filters etc).

[Qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) seemed like a good-enough choice and seems to do what I want.
However the latest commit is 2 years old, so I assume it's no more maintained.
Is there a more "standard" and up-to-date library that is available to use ?

Note that I'm looking for something that doesn't require another backend (eg Flask) to run computation, but just something like QGrid where it's a 100% JS component

Comment: if `Qgrid` works for you then use it.

Comment: @furas `Qgrid` is broken on Python 3.10. It seems it was last updated in 2020

Answer (score 1):

As of [two weeks ago](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid/issues/392), there seems to be [QgridNext](https://github.com/zhihanyue/qgridnext) as an alternative.

Seems to be a fork, the maintainer for this new repo doesn't seem to be associated to the previous group.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. And thanks to the author of the fork. Really needed and appreciated.